# Exception calling "TogglePoolOutOfService" with "4" argument(s): "SOAP header Action was not understood."

Tags: powershell, web-services

I'm trying to run a web service from Powershell and I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$PoolID
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$OOS
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$REF
    )

$ws=New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://0040_uat.welcom.servicebroker.server/WelcomRTIAdminUtility.svc

$ws.TogglePoolOutOfService($PoolID,$OOS,[ref]$REF,[ref]$REF)

}

Run-webservice -PoolID 11 -OOS $true -REF $true
```

I was initially getting `Cannot find an overload for "TogglePoolOutOfService" and the argument count: "4".`

If I run the call with no parameters it shows me the following overloads

```
OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                                                                    
-------------------                                                                                                                                                                    
void TogglePoolOutOfService(int poolId, bool poolIdSpecified, [ref] bool TogglePoolOutOfServiceResult, [ref] bool TogglePoolOutOfServiceResultSpecified)
```

I think it's probably something to do with the way I'm setting my parameters but I'm struggling to work out what is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're pasing a reference to a reference variable, not a reference to a boolean variable. Type of `$REF` should be `[bool]`, or if you're not interested in the results, just pass `[ref]$null`

Comment: I've changed that and now I get "Exception calling "TogglePoolOutOfService" with "4" argument(s): "SOAP header Action was not understood."" I've also edited the code in the question to match what it is now.